# ng update does not check or update @angular-devkit packages

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have angular CLI 7.3.0. According to the release description [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v7.3.0), This release also involved releasing `@angular-devkit/build-angular 0.13.0`.

As you can see in my screenshot below, I have @angular-devkit/build-angular, @angular-devkit/architect, @angular-devkit/build-optimizer, @angular-devkit/build-webpack all at version 0.10.2.

I then do an `ng update`, and the CLI tells me that everything is in order. Why? Shouldn't it tell me that I need to update all of the previously mentioned packages to 0.13.0?

Or better yet, shouldn't those packages automatically update when I do an `ng update @angular/cli`? That is the command I did to update to CLI 7.3.0, and the @angular-devkit packages did not update
[image]

Answer (score 11):

This works for me

```
ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Angular 16.

ng update @angular/cli updates those packages (and more)

```
ng update @angular/cli
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 16.1.3 to perform the update.
✔ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: npm
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 93 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular-devkit/build-angular @ "16.1.3" (was "15.1.2")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cli @ "16.1.3" (was "15.1.4")...
    Updating package.json with dependency ng-packagr @ "16.1.0" (was "15.1.1")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular-devkit/core @ "16.1.3" (was "15.1.2")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular-devkit/schematics @ "16.1.3" (was "15.1.4")...
```

Answer (score -1):

use these commands.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache verify (if npm > 5)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: `ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular`    
worked for me.    

As a sidenote, I was able to successfully run this, prior:     
`npm update angular-cli`