# Instead change the require of index.js, to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, nft

Trying to work with node/javascript/nfts, I am a noob and followed along a tutorial, but I get this error:

```
error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module [...] is not supported. Instead change the require of index.js [ in my file...]  to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules
```

My understanding is that they've updated the node file, so i need a different code than that in the tutorial, but i don't know which one I'm supposed to change, where and to what. Please be as specific as you can

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const path = require("path")
const basePath = process.cwd();
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readdirSync(`${basePath}/build/images`).foreach(file).forEach(file => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(`${basePath}/build/images/${file}`);
    formData.append('file',fileStream);

    let url = 'https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/files';

    let options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authorization: '[...]',
      },
      body: formData
    };
    
    fetch(url, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
       const fileName = path.parse(json.file_name).name;
       let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json/${fileName}.json`);
       let metaData = JSON.parse(rawdata);

       metaData.file_url = json.ipfs_url;

       fs.writeFileSync(`${basePath}/build/json${fileName}.json`, JSON.stringify(metaData, null, 2));

       console.log(`${json.file_name} uploaded & ${fileName}.json updated!`);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));
})
```

Comment: I did npm i node-fetch@2.6.1, it seems like it fixed it,  then i wrote node utils/nftport/uploadFiles.js in the terminal (dont know the proper terms) and it said "file is not defined" is these problems connected? what wrong did i do?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

It is because of the `node-fetch` package. As recent versions of this package only support ESM, you have to downgrade it to an older version `node-fetch@2.6.1` or lower.

`npm i node-fetch@2.6.1`

This should solve the issue.

Comment: how do you know this was the error, I am going mad since last one hour

Comment: it is in the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#user-content-commonjsCommonJS
node-fetch from v3 is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require().

If you cannot switch to ESM, please use v2 which remains compatible with CommonJS. Critical bug fixes will continue to be published for v2.

`npm install node-fetch@2`

Comment: The instructions by @PhilWilliammee are the way to go as `2.6.1` has an audit warning now.

Comment: 2.6.7 also works, frens

Comment: From [got-install](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#install), the author writes a convert ESM guide [Pure ESM package](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c) might be helpful.

Answer (score 45):

No need to use the old version.
You can use this line instead of "require"

```
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me.

can you just describe what this does?

Comment: @rashidotm This defines `fetch` as a function taking an arbitrary number of parameters, that is implemented as the resolution of the `Promise` returned by `import`, chained (`.then`) to then apply the arguments provided to the function returned by the `import` when it resolves.

This is ok because `fetch` already returns a `Promise`, so chaining it with the also asynchronous function `import` will not change anything. But I had the same problem for the package `chalk`, which has synchronous functions, and there it would not work.

Comment: a more readable version of the same thing which also handles errors https://stackoverflow.com/a/77608593/1205871

Answer (score 12):

This can occur when you install the latest version of a package that has an issue with modules import.

In my case, I was getting the error after installing the latest version of  `crypto-random-string` package. To know which package is causing this error, check the message preceding the above error reported. In my case, it read like so:
`error: uncaughtException: require() of ES Module /Users/myname/Documents/mydir/anotherdir/my-project/node_modules/crypto-random-string/index.js`

To fix it, I only downgraded to an earlier version by doing the following:

1. `yarn remove crypto-random-string`
2. `yarn add crypto-random-string@3.3.1`

Comment: Shocking how I had the exact same issue and module.

Answer (score 11):

Go to your package.json file and write:

```
"type": "module",
```

above debug.

and instead of writing `require('chalk')` in the .js file, change it to `import chalk from 'chalk'`

Comment: This can not work mixed ems npm deps and cmj npm deps.

Comment: Yes, this will work for only some situations, in my case adding `"type": "module"` fixed this issue but other things became incompatible

Comment: This causes a host of other problems. [Here](https://github.com/epicweb-dev/invariant/issues/10) is where I'm at today, yay.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error on common.js in angular-devkit after upgrading to angular 13. I found that this is missed during the upgrade:

[ng update does not check or update @angular-devkit packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566017/ng-update-does-not-check-or-update-angular-devkit-packages)

I got rid of it using:

```
ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Comment: unfortunately, @angular-devkit/build-angular was up to date and still getting the same error

Answer (score 3):

[ps-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-list) is an example package with this issue. This works:

```
(async () => {
  const psList = await import('ps-list').then(psl => psl.default)
  // YOUR CODE HERE
})().catch(console.error)
```

This also logs on error instead of remaining silent!

This answer is essentially the same but I found it somewhat confusing and it doesn't handle errors! https://stackoverflow.com/a/75281896/1205871

Comment: Simple and straightforward!

Answer (score 1):

Another option that worked for me is using the package [node-fetch-native](https://github.com/unjs/node-fetch-native) that redistributes `node-fetch` with some polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

In your .tsconfig:

change `"module": "nodenext",` to `"module": "commonjs",` if your projects allows.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was using node version 20.1.0 as i had nvm as my package manager. if you use nvm you can do so by using `nvm use 20.1.0` if you have the version or `nvm install 20.1.0` if you do not have 20.1.0

Answer (score -5):

I added the one statement extra you can see this `"type": "module",` statement, written down after `license`.

```
"author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^5.0.1"
    
  }
}
```