# A dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I got the below error when I'm trying to run `npm install`. Error Message:

```
taskRepository: Failed to require task module for setTimestamp: require() of ES Module ......\node_modules\dateformat\lib\dateformat.js from .....\setTimestamp.js not 
supported.
Instead change the require of dateformat.js in .....\setTimestamp.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

In setTimestamp.js file, we have

```
const stringReplacer = require("@ui5/builder").processors.stringReplacer;
const df = require("dateformat");
```

This is a SAPUI5 based cloud application and we've 2 package.json files.
Under Root folder:

```
"version": "1.2.0",
"devDependencies": {
    "@ui5/builder": "^2.11.5",
    "@ui5/cli": "^2.14.10",
    "@wdio/cli": "7.23.0",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "7.23.0",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "7.23.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "7.23.0",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "7.23.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "7.23.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "chromedriver": "^104.0.0",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "5.5.0",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "opa-e2e": "^1.0.11",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.5",
    "type": "module",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2",
    "wdio-cucumber-reporter": "0.0.2",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^4.4.3"
},
"resolutions": {
        "terser": ">=5.14.2",
        "markdown-it": ">=12.3.2",
        "marked": ">=4.0.10",
        "shelljs": ">=0.8.5",
        "ejs": ">=3.1.7",
        "node-fetch": ">=2.6.7",
        "got": ">=11.8.5",
        "follow-redirects": ">=1.14.8",
        "minimist": ">=1.2.6"
   }
```

Inner one:

```
"ui5": {
        "dependencies": [
            "ui5-middleware-livereload",
            "ui5-middleware-simpleproxy",
            "ui5-middleware-servestatic",
            "@dwc/ui5-middleware-dwc"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@dwc/ui5-middleware-dwc": "^1.4.2-20220817085704",
        "@ui5/cli": "^2.14.10",
        "dateformat": "^5.0.3",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^8.22.0",
        "karma": "6.4.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
        "karma-coverage": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
        "karma-qunit": "^4.1.2",
        "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
        "karma-ui5": "2.4.0",
        "nyc": "^15.1.0",
        "qunitjs": "^2.4.1",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "shelljs": "^0.8.5",
        "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
        "ui5-middleware-livereload": "^0.7.0",
        "ui5-middleware-servestatic": "^0.4.0",
        "ui5-middleware-simpleproxy": "^0.9.1",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "7.3.2"
    }, 


 "resolutions": {
        "terser": ">=5.14.2",
        "markdown-it": ">=12.3.2",
        "marked": ">=4.0.10",
        "ua-parser-js": ">=0.7.24",
        "log4js": ">=6.4.0",
        "karma": ">=6.3.16",
        "follow-redirects": ">=1.14.8",
        "minimist": ">=1.2.6"
    }
```

I tried to fix this issue by using:

```
npm i node-fetch@2.6.1
```

Or, in package.json file , wrote `"type": "module"`  etc.
Ref: [Instead change the require of index.js, to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541068/instead-change-the-require-of-index-js-to-a-dynamic-import-which-is-available)

Could anyone please help me to solve the error? Any help would be much appreciate.
Request: Please don't close the question. I know it's duplicate question, however I couldn't find any solution, tried how much I found.Thank you

Comment: Please show your `package.json`

Comment: Hi, I've added the two json files. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error requiring `node-fetch`. The solution was

```
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nodemon

1. install nodemon if not installed
2. create a nodemon.json file in root directory
3. nodemon.json file should contain an object with a variable name to use for the environment. (i.e.
   {"env": {
   "enviornment_variable1":"somevalue",
   "environment_varialbe2":"somevalue"
   }
   }
   )
4. Use the environment variable through process.env.environment_variable_key. In your something.js file you would make a variable for the environment variable (i.e. const x = process.env.enviornment_variable1
5. Make sure to restart server