# Getting an error of 503 when deploying my Api NodeJs in Cpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment

So I already deployed my website Nodejs + MySQL, but the problem is I get an error of

`503 Service Unavailable The server is temporarily busy, try again later!`

so I saw a thread : [Instead change the require of index.js, to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541068/instead-change-the-require-of-index-js-to-a-dynamic-import-which-is-available), I followed the thread and install the

`npm i node-fetch@2.6.1`

after that, I also went back to my `setup nodejs` and stop the process and `npm install` it again and received the same error, when I check my `stderr.log` i get an error of this

/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:48
var app = require(startupFile);
^

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/ppsconl2/nodejs/index.js from /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at startApplication (/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:48:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js:16:1) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21"
  }
}
```

The hosting's node js is `v18.9.1` while in my pc is `v18.14.1`

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I have the exact same error. I think it's being caused by "/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lsnode.js". This is the first app I have ever tried to deploy and I am pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your main js file (`index.js`) into `app.mjs` (maybe `index.mjs` works nowadays, but some cPanel documentations say the main file must be named `app`. Don't forget to restart your application in cPanel Web Applications after updating the file name. I also recommend to stop the application prior to renaming the file.

#### OR

You can also update your application to use only `require()` instead of `import`